# Eclipse PDT HTML attribute assignment operator colour?

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax, colors, eclipse-pdt

I would like to know how to change the colour of the equality sign and double quotes for html documents in the eclipse PDT IDE. I can change most colours in Preferences -> Web & XML -> HTML Files -> syntax coloring, but can't change the characters `=` or `"` e.g. in an anchor tag `<a href="">`.

How to change these colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the only remaining element being overridden by the default *Foreground color* in the general text editors options.

Comment: Please select this as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to check out the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) plugin and [Apatana](http://www.aptana.com/), both of which give you lots more syntax color highlighting control (and more).